# How to run a PHP sentence directly from the command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I know that `php -a` will allow let me execute interactively PHP sentences and that I can create a file and pass it to the `php -f` command, but what I want is execute a single PHP sentence without have to create a file neither go to interactive mode. Lets suppose that the sentence is `echo "testing";`. I'm on Ubuntu OS, I said that cos seem to me that the solution is around making some mix of php command with shell pipe.

Comment: `php --help` and read the options?

Comment: I already read the manual page when did the question of course, but seem that I miss the '-r' option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

that would be

```
 php -r 'echo "something";'
```

Answer (score 2):

try [phpsh](https://github.com/facebook/phpsh) by facebook. It is very good for testing your onliners.